# How do I disable pull to refresh behavior in Trusted Web Activity (TWA)?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, chromium, trusted-web-activity, twa, bubblewrap

I have my PWA app which has this code in main.css file.

```
  @media all and (display-mode: fullscreen) {
    overscroll-behavior: none;
  }
```

And when added to Homescreen and launched in fullscreen mode (set in manifest.json), pull-to-refresh is disabled as expected.

However, in TWA case:

When I create signed APK using https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap
pull-to-refresh behavior is not disabled.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up making a Javascript workaround:

First I updated **twaManifest** in `build.gradle` file.

The following line:

```
launchUrl: '/?utm_source=twa'
```

And I added this piece of js to add css class to body element when twa query param is detected:

```
export const disablePullToRefreshTWA = () => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const myParam = urlParams.get('utm_source');
    if (myParam === 'twa') {
        document.body.classList.add('twa-app');
    }
};
```

and my `main.css` now has:

```
body.twa-app {
  overscroll-behavior: none;
}
```

Edit: I kept my pwa (display-mode) media query for PWA add to HomeScreen case

Comment: Don't confuse the real behavior of [UTM parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_parameters) by misusing them. It'll bite your analytics, if you use any or it might be stripped by a privacy-based extension.

Answer (score 1):

That's All

```
body {
overscroll-behavior: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome on Android refreshes the page when you scroll past the top boundary. This can be prevented by setting "overscroll-behavior" to "none" on the "html" element.

```
html { margin: 0; overscroll-behavior: none; }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior#preventing_an_underlying_element_from_scrolling